# My game is not saving the data I want it to save

Tags: lua, roblox

So, what I'm trying to make is a simple sword fighting game. I am following the tutorials of a YouTuber called AlvinBlox. I identically copied down his datastore code, while trying to learn what the code does, and the code is supposed to save the currency when the player leaves the game. For example, if you were to leave the game with 50 money, the server is supposed to save that money, and once you enter the game again, the saved data or money loads and you get ur original amount of money back. Well, in my situation that's not happening, whenever I join a game and go to the console to give myself a set amount of money, then I rejoin the game only to find out the data isn't saved at all. This is only a part of my actual stats script if you wish to see more let me know. **To let you know, i also added this, "local dataStores = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("MunnyDataStore")", at the very top of my code**. Please help me, thank you!

```
    local player_data 

    pcall(function() 

        player_data = dataStores:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-Munny") 

    end)

     if player_data ~= nil then
         -- Player has saved data, load it in
         munny.Value = player_data
     else
         -- Else new player
         munny.Value = defaultCash

     end




 local bindableEvent = Instance.new("BindableEvent")


 game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player) 

     pcall(function() 

         dataStores:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-Munny",player.leaderstats.Munny.Value)
         print("Saved")
         playersLeft -= 1
         bindableEvent:Fire()

     end)


 end)

 game:BindToClose(function() 

     while playersLeft > 0 do
         bindableEvent.Event:Wait()

     end

 end)
```

Comment: Heyo Anonymous, what happens when you start up the code? Is `player_data` always nil? Is `munny` created and parented anywhere? You've got print statements in your code, are any of them showing up in the Output window?  When trying to save the data, what is `player.leaderstats.Munny.Value` equal to?

Comment: um hi, well in order to test the data saving part i manually join my game through the roblox website instead of testing it in the studio. Then I go to the chat bar, and open up the console, and I dont find any errors. So i proceed to type down game.Player."username".leaderstats.Munny.Value = 900. That changes the amount of munny i have to 900. Then I rejoin the entire game, but I dont find my munny or data saved. The player.leaderstats.Munny.Value, is equal to the munny inside the leaderstats folder, which is inside the player.

Comment: if you want to, you can test this in Studio. Check out https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Saving-Player-Data. Mind the warning : "API access must be active in order to access and test data stores in Roblox Studio. See the Data Stores article for instructions on enabling API access."